# How can I debug a Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have hundreds of stored procedures in my SQL Server 2012 database.

From my c# code, I am calling one of the stored procedures which in turn calls another stored procedure and so on.

There is a failure in stored procedure execution. I need to debug it. For that I need to know what are the values which are sent as parameter when calling stored procedure inside another stored procedure .

I cannot alter the stored procedure, is there any way to `Watch` and `StackTrace` stored procedures?

Yes, I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: check my post it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging stored procedure, you must be on the PC which has the database engine and then simple you put a break point on it, pass parameter value if it have parameters and then click on debug.

[Debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billramo/archive/2009/04/11/transact-sql-debugger-for-sql-server-2008-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't use Visual Studio and set a breakpoint where your SP is being called to examine the parameters your best option is to use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx). With Profiler you can examine queries which are being run and look at their duration.

If you're unable to use profiler (maybe you're on an express edition) then your only option is to create a logging table and temporally change your SP to insert your parameters into it - this option is far from ideal as it requires changing the code to analyse it.